# kubernetes nginx service not opening from browser

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, kubernetes

I am running nginx pod and Loadbalancer service in a minikube on ubuntu 20.4. However, I am unable to open  nginx default home page from the browser. I couldn't find any issue from my Yaml files of the output endpoints. Do I need to do anything else to hit my Nginx pod from browser?

**Yaml file:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service  
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      nodePort: 30001
      targetPort: 8080
```

**kubectl describe svc nginx-service output:**

```
Name:                     nginx-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=nginx
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.105.99.220
IPs:                      10.105.99.220
Port:                     <unset>  8081/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30001/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.3:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

**kubectl describe svc nginx-service**

|-----------|---------------|-------------|-----------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |     NAME      | TARGET PORT |             URL             |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|-----------------------------|
| default   | nginx-service |        8081 | http://192.168.99.101:30001 |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|-----------------------------|

**Curl output**

```
curl http://192.168.99.101:30001
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.101 port 30001: Connection refused
```

Comment: May be set containerPort to 80 in the deployment

Comment: Thanks. That worked. What is the reason? Do we need to run Nginx always on port-80?

Comment: nginx by default listen on port 80.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a non-default port(8080) to listen on a nginx container. You should change it to port `80` where nginx by default listen. Alternatively you can change(why?!) the port over which nginx listen as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47364019/how-to-change-the-port-of-nginx-when-using-with-docker).